# Enforcing inactivity timeout using passport with auth0

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, auth0, express-session

I am trying to enforce user logout after a period of inactivity, but I have had no luck.

I have a node web application that is using Auth0 and Passport for authentication. I have set the inactivity timeout on the tenant (from the tenant settings page on Auth0) and modified the jwt expiration on the application settings page, but none of these changes have had an effect on the behavior of the application.

Other information: in the application settings, I have set this as a Regular Web Application, and I have tried Basic and Post for Token Endpoint Authentication Method.

I have followed the [node JS quickstart guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs/01-login) that Auth0 provides, as well as one of their [blog posts](https://auth0.com/blog/create-a-simple-and-secure-node-express-app/) using express-session, passport, and passport-auth0. I am configuring express-session and passport in the order that these two posts show, so I don't think that is the issue. I am guessing that there is an extra step needed to implement this functionality, but I can't find any documentation on Auth0's site or Passport's. I am also confused as to why these values are configurable if they don't seem to have any effect.

When I manually set the maxAge value in express-session's settings, I do see the application make a call to Auth0. However, this is not based on inactivity, and that is my primary goal here.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Auth0 Community and you are able to configure this as a setting with your Auth0 Tenant as described in the below documentation:

> The intent of this approach allows the session to go inactive if the
>   user is no longer present, but otherwise provides a means to trigger
>   the silent token refresh so that they can continue their session
>   without the need to be prompted again for credentials.
>
> Inactivity Timer: A rolling timer should be added to the React SDK
>   wrapper that aligns with the maximum idle lifetime of the Auth0
>   session. Each time a token is returned to the application the timer
>   should be reset.
>
> Timeout Modal: When the timer hits 60 seconds from expiration a
>   timeout modal should render requesting the user to logout or continue
>   their session.
>
> Continue the session: In the case the user chooses to continue their
>   session the getTokenSilently() method can be used to request a new
>   token without needing to redirect the user from the page they are
>   currently interacting with.
>
> Logging out: In the case the user chooses to logout the logout()
>   method should be called to assure the Auth0 session is ended as well.
>
> Idle Timeout: In the case that the idle timeout is reached no
>   immediate action is necessary. To handle the fact that the user may
>   still be active in another tab, the behavior should not be to log the
>   user out.

https://auth0.com/docs/sessions/concepts/session-lifetime

I hope this helps you on your quest!